# MySql : Drop all existing primary keys and insert a new auto increment primary key

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

In a MySql Database table there is already two primary ( composite ) and the table has around 50000 row.

Now I need to remove those primary keys and add a new auto increment primary key `id`.

I need all my row should be unchanged and will be assigned unique id.

Now what will be the query string to perform this .

I have tried the following code but got error

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 1*

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP PRIMARY KEY ADD `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer, I was missing a comma between two sql statement.

Correct code will be

```
  ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't simply *drop* the existing primary keys. Replace them with `not null unique` constraints, and *then* add a surrogate key. Here's why. (PostgreSQL, but the principles are the same.)

```
create table elements (
  chemical_symbol varchar(2) primary key,
  atomic_number int not null unique,
  element_name varchar (35) not null unique
);

insert into elements values
('H', 1, 'hydrogen'),
('He', 2, 'helium'),
('Li', 3, 'lithium'),
('Be', 4, 'beryllium')
-- many more rows
;
```

If you just drop the existing primary key constraint and add a surrogate key, like this . . .

```
-- DON'T DO THIS.
alter table elements drop constraint elements_pkey,
add column element_id serial primary key;
```

. . . you lose the business rule that "chemical_symbol" must be unique.

```
insert into elements (chemical_symbol, atomic_number, element_name)
values ('H', 5, 'boron');

select * from elements
order by chemical_symbol;
```

```
chemical_symbol  atomic_number  element_name  element_id
--
Be               4              beryllium     4
H                1              hydrogen      1
H                5              boron         5
He               2              helium        2
Li               3              lithium       3
```

Now two elements have the chemical_symbol 'H'. That's a mistake.

Instead, replace the existing primary key constraint with `not null` and `unique` constraints. Then add a surrogate key.

```
-- Do this instead.
alter table elements drop constraint elements_pkey,
add constraint elements_chemical_symbol_key unique (chemical_symbol),
alter column chemical_symbol set not null,
add column element_id serial primary key;
```

Now if you try to insert a row that has a duplicate chemical_symbol, the dbms will raise an error.

```
insert into elements (chemical_symbol, atomic_number, element_name)
values ('H', 5, 'Boron');
```

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "elements_chemical_symbol_key"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (chemical_symbol)=(H) already exists.
```